# Ionicons not showing up

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, svg, ionic2, ionic4

I have checked all the possible solutions for this problem, but I am unable to find something that would crack this nut. Therefore please, there is no need of telling me that this has been answered before.

I am following a lecture up on udemy where the fellow course teacher is going through Ionic. We're just going through some basic features right now, like adding icons, buttons, containers etc. Basic stuff

But i have ran into a problem... I am trying to add a Icon "close" straight from the ionicons.com website by using the code they suggest 
   `<ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>` this is what i am using.

I only have a `index.html` file, since that is what the teacher is doing on the tutorial.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Budget Planner</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic.js"> 
</script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/css/ionic.bundle.css" 
rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<ion-app> 
<ion-header>
<ion-toolbar color="primary">
<ion-title> Budget Planner </ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content> 
<ion-grid>
<ion-row>
<ion-col size-md="6" offset-md="3">
<ion-card>
<ion-card-title> New Expense </ion-card-title>
<ion-card-content>
<ion-item>
<ion-label position="floating">Expense Reason</ion-label>
<ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
<ion-label position="floating">Expense Amount</ion-label>
<ion-input type="number"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-button fill="outline" color="danger">
<ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon> Clear </ion-button>
<ion-button> Add Expense </ion-button>
</ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
</ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
</ion-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Pretty much just created some grids, and buttons, and etc. All the stuff is pretty easy to understand but the only thing i cant figure out is why it wont give me the close icon in order for me to proceed with the tutorials.
I would expect this to just spit the close button, but instead i get the following

```
[ionic] Deprecated script, please remove: <script 
src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic.js"></script>
To improve performance it is recommended to set the differential scripts 
in the head as follows:
<script type="module" 
src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"> 
</script>
<script nomodule="" src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
(anonymous) @ VM977 ionic.js:25
(anonymous) @ VM977 ionic.js:27
ios-close.svg:1 
GET https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@4.7.1/dist/svg/ios-close.svg
```

This is shown in my browser console. Upon expanding the "GET https://unpkg.com..." I get the following

> Cannot find "/dist/svg/ios-close.svg" in @ionic/core@4.7.1

Anyone with a solution?

Comment: are you using Angular 8?

Comment: Have you tried to do exactly what the console says? If I replace `<script 
src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic.js"></script>` with `<script type="module" 
src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"> 
</script>
<script nomodule="" src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>`, it works without any complaints.

Comment: Doing what the console tries to show as a solution does solve the problem. Thanx a lot :) 

THe first time i tried doing the console solution i only added the first line of script not the second one. Never came into my head that it would need the other line too.

Answer (score 3):

Place the following `<script>` near the end of your page, right before the closing body tag, to enable them.It worked for me.

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.0.0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>
```